# Return Database Roles a User is not a member of

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the database roles of a specific users via stored procedure with the following:

```
USE SQLEXP_ALLEN
GO

SELECT 
    DP1.name AS RoleName,   
    ISNULL(DP2.name, 'No members') AS UserName
FROM 
    sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.database_principals AS DP1 ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.database_principals AS DP2 ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
WHERE 
    DP1.type = 'R'
    AND DP2.name = @username
ORDER BY 
    DP1.name;
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to come up with roles the user is NOT a member of. HELP!

Comment: You where predicate of DP2.Name has turned your left join into an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I probably don't need so many CTEs but it explains the logic:
1)  Selct all roles
2)  Select all users
3)  Cross Join to get all combinations.
4)  Left outer join to role members to see which ones aren't members.
YOu can adjust each CTE to get what you need.

```
WITH    Roles ( RoleID, RoleName )
      AS ( SELECT rol.principal_id, 
                  rol.name  
           FROM sys.database_principals rol
           WHERE type = 'R'
         ),
    Users ( UserID, Username )
      AS ( SELECT   princ.principal_id ,
                    princ.name
           FROM     sys.database_principals princ
           WHERE    type IN ( 'U', 'G' )
         ),
    UsersAllRoles ( UserID, UserName, RoleID, RoleName )
      AS ( SELECT   Users.UserID, Users.Username, Roles.RoleID, 
             Roles.RoleName
           FROM     Users
                    CROSS JOIN Roles
         )

 SELECT  uar.UserID ,
    uar.UserName ,
    uar.RoleID ,
    uar.RoleName ,
    drm.role_principal_id
FROM    UsersAllRoles uar
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members drm 
    ON uar.UserID =drm.member_principal_id
    AND uar.RoleID = drm.role_principal_id
WHERE   drm.member_principal_id IS NULL;
```